# How to create training data for RASA NLU through program nodejs

Tags: mean-stack, spacy, rasa-nlu

How to create training data through program for RASA NLU?
Actually I am developing an application using MEAN stack, this application prepares the data that needs to be trained with RASA NLU.

But I don't know how to pass this info from my nodejs server to RASA NLU. Is there any supported api's to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rasa has a highly functional API as documented [here](https://rasa-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#).

To answer the specific question you can pass training data to the Rasa NLU API via the below commands:

If your training data is in a file:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:5000/train?project=my_project -d @data/examples/rasa/demo-rasa.json
```

If your training data is in json format:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'http://localhost:5000/train?project=test&fixed_model_name=tested-project' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data ' {
  "rasa_nlu_data": {
    "regex_features": [
      {
        "name": "zipcode",
        "pattern": "[0-9]{5}"
      }
    ],
    "entity_synonyms": [
      {
        "value": "chinese",
        "synonyms": ["Chinese", "Chines", "chines"]
      },
      {
        "value": "vegetarian",
        "synonyms": ["veggie", "vegg"]
      }
    ],
    "common_examples": []
  }
}'
```

Obviously you'll need to create the json file or payload. and in Node you wouldn't be using curl, but a library like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

I've written a [series of tutorials](https://blog.spg.ai/build-a-chatbot-with-rasa-nlu-dc2bfb55edb2) that may be good to help you get started interacting with Rasa's API.

Comment: so there is no another way where we can push the data directly from program or db like we do it for api.ai? in any case we have to create a file with the training data then process it , right?

Comment: No, my second example above showed how to directly POST JSON data to the API.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have few more questions about rasa as I am pretty new to this. if it's ok for you to discuss in messengers like fb/google, please provide me your email id

Comment: Why don't you join the Rasa NLU Gitter, lot's of people who can help there. https://gitter.im/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu

Answer (score 1):

I use a python [**library**](https://core.rasa.ai/installation.html) which is pretty good to power your conversational software, based on the latest Machine Learning research.

In order to use this, you have to build a python service that will interact with your nodejs server.

It would be also easy for you to scale and maintain both in the future

Or you can check this opensource app **https://github.com/aashreys/chatbot-example**

Comment: can't we directly push training data from program like we do it with api.ai?